# How to save logging info (info, debug, warning, error and critical) into a text file - Python

Tags: python, file, logging, netbeans

How can I save the logging info of my following code if the target file is "C:\test\Logging\logging.txt? The idea it's to keep writing as long the script is running.

```
import os
from threading import Timer
from os.path import isfile, join, exists
import shutil, time

PATH_TO_WATCH = "C:\\Test"

class FileReader:

    def __init__(self, path = None):
        self.path = path
        self.running = False
        self.timer = None

    def printFilesData(self, files):
        if self.path:
            timestamp = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S")
            destination = join(self.path, timestamp)
            for index, file in enumerate(files):
                if isfile(join(self.path, file)):
                    self.readAndMoveFile({"dest": destination, "name": file, "data": open(join(self.path, file))})

    def readAndMoveFile(self, fileData):

        print("\nArchivo:%s\n\n%s\n" % (fileData["name"], fileData["data"].read()))

        #El archivo debe ser cerrado para que se mueve
        fileData["data"].close()
        if not exists(fileData["dest"]):
            os.makedirs(fileData["dest"])
        try:
            shutil.move(join(self.path, fileData["name"]), fileData["dest"])
            print("\nArchivo \"%s\" movido \"%s\" a la carpeta.\n" % (fileData["name"], fileData["dest"]))
        except WindowsError as e:
            print(e)

    def listFiles(self):
        if self.path:
            return [file for file in os.listdir(self.path)]
        return None

    def stopWatching(self):
        print("\nNot watching.\n")
        self.timer.cancel()

    def complete(self):
        after = self.listFiles()
        added = [file for file in after if not file in self.lock]
        self.printFilesData(added)
        self.lock = after
        self.timer = Timer(5.0, self.complete)
        self.timer.start()

    def startWatching(self):
        if(self.path):
            self.lock = self.listFiles()
            print("\nDirectorio que se esta observando %s...\n" % self.path)
            self.printFilesData(self.lock)
            self.timer = Timer(5.0, self.complete)
            self.timer.start()
        else: print("Ruta sin definir.")

class Main():

    def __init__(self):
        self.reader = FileReader("C:\\Test")
        self.reader.startWatching()


if __name__ == '__main__':        
    Main()
```

I know I have to add the import logging and also:

```
logging.debug()
logging.info()
logging.warning()
logging.error()
logging.critical()
```

But I don't know how to apply  or where to put them

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There is a documentation with some examples to guide you [how the logging could be used in python](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html).

For a quick start see the following example, which writes the output into the file "logging.txt"

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='logging.txt')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.error('this is an error')
logger.info('this is an info')
```

the output in the file will be

```
ERROR:__main__:this is an error
INFO:__main__:this is an info
```

so you could place the `logger.info` ... everywhere in your script if needed.

Comment: Got it. But how can I specify the route /path where will the filename with the logs will be created? Because what my scripts does it's that every time a new files is moved or created in a directory, it will create a new folder and the file will be moved to the recently created folder. That's why I put the logging.txt in a folder named 'Logging'.

Comment: @Beta you could add the path to the configuration of `filename` i.e. `logging.basicConfig(filename='Logging/logging.txt')`

Comment: you mean that it should something like this
  "C:\test\Logging\logging.txt" ?

Comment: @Beta yes exactly.